# grpc server not working in docker-compose

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc

I build sample project with grpc server.in vs every things is ok and my project nice worked.
dokcer-compose.yaml is :

```
version: '3.3' 
services:
  grpcService:
    container_name: grpcserver
    image:  grpcImage
    ports:
      - "5003:5003"  //client
      - "5001:5001"  //grpc server
    restart: always
```

in project I set `http://127.0.0.1:5001` for grpc server

and set `http://127.0.0.1:5003` for client
I handle (grpc server worked with http)

when docker-compose up and call api ,get faild and grpc server not found , etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you must change CreateHostBuilder to this code in program.cs Grpc Server

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>().ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Listen(IPAddress.Any, 5001, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2;
                    });
                });
            });
}
```

`5001` is grpc Server Port.(change this port to your grpc server port)